# How to change the time after which I have to type my password again?

Tags: unity, 13.10

When I am logged in to Ubuntu 13.10 (Unity I guess) and nothing happens, the screen gets black. I am not logged out, but I need to type the password to be able to 'do' something again. How can I change this time?

If this is related to screensaver settings, I neither can find them in the System settings, nor in the application list, nor in the whitly thing on the upper left (dashboard)? So how to change this timeout after which the screen gets black and I am asked for the password again (after mouse movement etc).

Comment: Did you have a look at *System Settings -> Brightness & Lock*?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "System Settings" > "Brightness & Lock" and change the "Lock" section.

[image: screenshoot]